# How does one show that $\{ \frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{Z_{>0}}\} $is not compact in the standard topology?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

How does one show that $\{ \frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{Z_{>0}}\}$ is not compact in the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$?

I know this is not compact because if we take small enough intervals around the elements of a, we cannot have a finite subcovering. But i can't seem to think about an open covering that fails. I tried to get something in the form $\{(\frac{1}{n} - \epsilon,\frac{1}{n} + \epsilon)\}$, but one can note it is impossible to choose epsilon s.t

$0 \notin (\frac{1}{n} - \epsilon,\frac{1}{n} + \epsilon)$.

Comment: yes sorry about that xD. It is not compact i know that for sure

Comment: Can you simply use the fact that a compact set is closed and bounded, and your set is not closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $\{(\frac1n,2)\}$? . . .

Comment: this one works fine thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Compact implies closed and bounded but the set is not closed: it does not contain its limit point $0$.

Comment: maybe this sounds stupid but it is closed right? Can't we write the complement as a union of intervals in the form:

$(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}) \cup (1,\infty) \cup (-\infty,0)$

Comment: o ok i already see we get trouble in $0$ :)

Answer (score 2):

You can make the intervals smaller and smaller as you get close to zero.  Something like a cover of the form $(\frac 1n - \frac 1{2n^2},\frac 1n + \frac 1{2n^2})$

Comment: nice!, i should have thought of this instead of those unnecessarily difficult epsilon statements xD